# Format Date Time in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How to display date time in Angular2?

`{{dte}}`

It prints date `2014-10-10T11:42:28.000Z`

While I need it to print like:

`Oct 10, 2015`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use moment.js as a third party.

**amDateFormat pipe**

```
import {DateFormatPipe} from 'angular2-moment';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app',
      pipes: [DateFormatPipe],
      template: `
        Last updated: <time>{{myDate | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</time>
      `
    })

Prints Last updated: January 24, 2016
```

Documentation: https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment

Answer (score 11):

just use the pipe filter with ur {{dte}}...

> just use {{dte |date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}

it will give u your desired output :)

Comment: no its not working.   It gives errro "Invalid argument '2016-07-20T11:42:28.000Z' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: its working fine for me , i just confirmed your situation ... i was getting the date in same format as yours but after the filter i get the right result

Comment: perfect solution, it can be changed to any format you want like i used: date :'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'

Answer (score 8):

Use [date pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html):

```
{{dte | date}}
```

You can choose a predefined format (e.g. `shortDate`):

```
{{dte | date:'mediumDate'}}
```

Or specify your custom format:

```
{{dte | date:'MM dd, yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to use RFC time standard just write the following format `dd.MM.yy HH:mm`:

```
{{ yourDate | date:'dd.MM.yy HH:mm' }}
```

Output will be: `15.11.2018 16:38`